# Jsp default date format

Tags: java, jsp, date, formatting

Is it possible to change default formatting of Date object in JSP pages? Now I have some kind of formatting and I would like to change formatting without using fmt-tags, because that would mean I would have to type that formatting to all pages and there are many!

Comment: Are you using <%=myDate%> ? If it's the case... better you do what BalusC says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *without using fmt-tags*

Best is to create your own [custom taglib](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) which does exactly the same as JSTL [`fmt:formatDate`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html).

But why would you want to reinvent the wheel? Is it the "much" effort of replacing the code in JSP? Well, that's just *your* job :) It's basically as simple as following:

1. Drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. Declare `fmt` taglib in top of your JSP:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
   ```
3. Use `fmt:formatDate` on any bean's `java.util.Date` property.

   ```
   <fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" type="date" dateStyle="short" />
   ```

   Above example will print today's date as `10/01/25` for English locales and for example `25.01.10` for German locales. No worries anymore! :)

You would be almost already finished in the time you spent asking the question and waiting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, it is not possible as JSP will just invoke toString method on the object which you cannot override using settings. You have to do it manually.